# How to handle this response case

Tags: java, rest

I have an endpoint to which another team connects. This endpoint returns a response which is irrelevant to the team. It only cares if their input has reached us or not. But we have to do a lot of processing after that. Currently we just take in the request and respond How to handle this scenario. Below is the sample code.

```
@POST
public Response perform(Request request){
 //do something here that takes some time.
return Response.status(Httpstatus.OK).build();
}
```

What is the best way to make sure that the response goes back to the caller even though the processing keeps going on. I thought about async but wanted to check if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a

> 202 Accepted
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed. The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled.

including a Link where the result will be available.

```
@POST
public Response perform(Request request){
    //TODO attach the request to an asynch background job

    //pseudo code!
    return Response.status(ACCEPTED)
                   .location(/* URI where the result will be accessible*/) 
                   .build();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. It is worth adding in "_an indication of the request's current status_" - whilst not required, it is obviously very useful for the client to be able to determine whether the request is finished.

Comment: But how to send it before processing the request? That is the main question?

Comment: You have to do it asynchronous. This way the clients get the accepted-response right away and can look up the result with the location link you provide.

Comment: @user3310115 chuck the user data into a queue and return the response. Separately, take another thread pool take tasks and process them.